# hibernate: objects created in wrong order?

Tags: java, hibernate

I just switched from XML mapping to annotations and had to realize that my serialization class does not work any more!
I hope you can help me to find out the reason :)

I have a `School` class that contains an `Address`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="schools")
    public class School {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id", nullable=true)
    private Address address;
        ...
}
```

the `Address` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="addresses")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="street", nullable=false, updatable=true)
    private String street;      // with nr
    ...
}
```

I try to serialize like this:

```
sessionFactory = MyFactory.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            School mbs = new School("interesting school");
            Address a = new Address("garden street 5","12345", "somewhere");
            mbs.setAddress(a);

            session.save(mbs);
            tx.commit();
```

This worked before with XML, but now doesn't..

The first Hibernate query action visible on the console is:
Hibernate: insert into schools (address_id, layout_id, name) values (?, ?, ?)

Therefore an error occurs: ERROR: Column 'address_id' cannot be null

How can I fix this?

.

Those are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE schools(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(50),

    address_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    layout_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES addresses(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_layout FOREIGN KEY (layout_id) REFERENCES layout_headers(id),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE addresses(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street CHAR(55),
    zip CHAR(6),
    city CHAR(60),

    CONSTRAINT addr_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In my hibernte.cfg.xml I have the following:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
     ...
        <mapping class="creator.models.school.Address" />
        <mapping class="creator.models.school.Report" />
        <mapping class="creator.models.school.School" />
        <mapping class="creator.models.school.SchoolClass" />
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Try to set `cascade` for `@ManyToOne` annotation to `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: You need to specify `cascade` value to `@ManyToOne`or store `address` before setting to `School`. By default there is no cascading. I always prefer later.

Comment: You are right! ;) Thanks a lot!! I will better go and search for my concentration, which is apparently somewhere outside, playing in the snow -.-

Would you move your comment to an answer so that I can mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `cascade` property of `@ManyToOne` annotation on `address` field of `School` class to save address before school. For example, `CascadeType.ALL`